# Weird characters inserted by tapping space twice in Joomla? (see screenshot)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, joomla

Please see the below screenshot. There are unnecessary 'A' characters in my site.

[image]

How to remove them from Joomla's Database?

Comment: Well if that is in your database why don't you just edit it in database via phpmyadmin?

Comment: Thanks for replay but I have already tried this solution. But whenever my client updates data, it automatically adds these weird characters. I think it is the problem of charset type of the Database. Please brief me if you know about charset types.

Comment: Character type of table field should be utf-8 general ci. What is the content of the field in database? Does it have some weird characters?

Comment: It appears that some step in the process converts two consecutive spaces to a no-break space. (It might be leaving one space as normal, and converting the other. I can't tell from the screenshot.) A no-break space is character U+00A0. When no-break space is converted to UTF-8, its representation is C2 A0. If this UTF-8 string is then treated as a single-byte encoding such as Windows-1252, or if it is double-encoded to UTF-8, it becomes the two-character sequence "Â ".